# How to get MQTT subscribe to the correct Queue in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm building a notification system that will be integrated across many different clients including web-apps, winforms desktop, and an android app.

I have successfully created a server side lib that can post a message via AQMP to a queue with a name based on a Tenant- and User-Id. It can post notifications to the user when specific back-end processes have completed. And I can see the messages coming in via the "Queues and Streams" tab of the management plugin. So far so good.

For the web-based client I added the MQTT plugin as well as the MQTT-over-WebSockets plugin. Then I tried to get a web-based client to subscribe to the same queue via mqtt using the `mqtt.js` library. However I cannot get it to subscribe to a specific queue. I used `client.subscribe('MyQueueName', { qos: 2 }` but instead it creates a queue with a name like `mqtt-subscription-mqttjs_RandomChars`. And 'RandomChars' does not resemble anything like 'MyQueueName'.

I can send messages to the client via the management plugin, and they arrive promptly. However How do I get the client to pull the messages from the existing queue instead of creating a new one?

In addition, is there a way to disable incoming messages from the MQTT client? For now it is intended to be only one-way communication.